# How can I display three random exercises from an array every time a button is pressed using React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to display a list of 3 random exercises every time you press a button and change those 3 exercises on each button press

it chooses a random workout correctly in the console, but I'm not sure how to make it display and update correctly using React.

how can I make it so it displays a random 3 exercises every time the button is pressed. I've seen ways of doing it using only JS but am curious how to do this with React.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Workout extends Component {
render() {
    const upperExercises = [
        "test1",
        "test2",
        "test3"
    ]

    const lowerExercises = [
        "test4",
        "test5",
        "test6"
    ]

    const coreExercises = [
        "test7",
        "test8",
        "test9"
    ]

    function getAll() {
        let randomUpper = upperExercises[Math.floor(Math.random() * upperExercises.length)];
        console.log(randomUpper)

        let randomLower = lowerExercises[Math.floor(Math.random() * lowerExercises.length)];
        console.log(randomLower)

        let randomCore = coreExercises[Math.floor(Math.random() * coreExercises.length)];
        console.log(randomCore)

    }
    return (
        <section>
            <button onClick={() => { getAll() }}>TEST</button>
            <p>DISPLAY OUTPUT</p>
        </section>
    )
}
}

 export default Workout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. You can randomly get the values from your arrays and then setState of the values so you can access them easily in your `<p/>` tags.

I changed your `getAll` function to an arrow function to avoid having to bind to this . It's more simpler for beginners to use Es6 arrow functions. Let me know if this worked . Good Luck!!

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

const upperExercises = [
    "test1",
    "test2",
    "test3"
]

const lowerExercises = [
    "test4",
    "test5",
    "test6"
]

const coreExercises = [
    "test7",
    "test8",
    "test9"
]

class Workout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        //initialise state
        this.state = {
            lower ='',
            upper ='',
            core ='',
        }
    }

    //Changed your function to arrow function to avoid binding and its
    // a simplier way of doing it
    getAll = () => {
        const randomUpper = Math.floor(Math.random() * upperExercises.length);
        const upper = upperExercises[randomUpper]
        //Get the random value and set the state to that value
        this.setState({
            upper: upper
        })

        const randomLower = Math.floor(Math.random() * lowerExercises.length);
        const lower = lowerExercises[randomLower]
        this.setState({
            lower: lower
        })

        const randomCore = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomCore.length);
        const core = coreExercises[randomCore]
        this.setState({
            core: core
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <section>
                <button onClick={this.getAll}>TEST</button>
                <p>Upper {this.state.upper}</p>
                <p>Lower {this.state.lower}</p>
                <p>Core {this.state.core}</p>
            </section>
        )
    }

}

export default Workout
```

Comment: I've made the changes and it now says that 'getAll' is not defined. if I change it back from an arrow function to function getAll() { it gives me the error "cannot read property setState of undefined"

Comment: I have updated my answer the problem was that you put `render` in the wrong place so I didn't see it . So therefore `getAll` became undefined. You should be able to see it work now check my answer again . Let me know how it goes